# Asynchronous Thumbnail Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a problem with WPF's thumbnail creation. While I can create a thumbnail from and image in a different thread, I cannot transfer it to the main UI thread.

The conversion into a thumbnail has already been handled, so that's not an issue anymore; this is how I'm doing that right now:

```
public ImageSource Image
{
    get
    {
      BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

      bi.BeginInit();
      bi.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
      bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
      bi.UriSource = new Uri(value.ToString());
      bi.EndInit();

      return bi;
    }
}

<Image Source="{Binding Image, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

How do I manage to pass the thumbnail to the the mainthread?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I would also strongly suggest not to create the BitmapImage in the `Image` property getter. The binding infrastructure may access the property multiple times, and that would create a new BitmapImage on every call.

Comment: I tried it within the convert before, but it wouldn't work asynchronally. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this matter?

Comment: Which "convert"? Your code shows a read-only property. Calling `Freeze()` on the BitmapImage will make it cross-thread accessible.

Comment: My first idea was: <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding File.FullName, Converter={StaticResource UriToBitmapConverter}, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}"></Image> and create the thumbnail im Converter.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question, or ask another question. Besides that, a binding converter is called synchronously, even if the binding is set to be asynchronous. Only the property getter is called asynchronously.

Comment: You may probably keep the BitmapImage creation in the getter, but also keep the created BitmapImage in a private field. When the getter is called another time, just return the field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the BitmapImage cross-thread accessible, you have to freeze it. You should also keep the created BitmapImage in case the getter is called multiple times.

```
private BitmapImage image;

public ImageSource Image
{
    get
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = new Uri(value.ToString());
            image.EndInit();
            image.Freeze(); // here
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Clemens, its Work.